# Why File.getParent() returns a path without slashes in windows?

Tags: java, file, parent

I have a java programe which works well in linux, but it returns wrong values in windows. 
I have a File variable and I try to retrieve its parent path with getParent() method. The result in windows is a path without slashes.

```
...
File store = fileChooser.getSelectedFile ();  
System.out.println(store.getParent()); 
// prints C:UsersMynameDesktopTest
// expected C:/Users/Myname/Desktop/Test
```

Anyone knows the cause of this problem ?

Comment: Do you see that directly in the console or is there anything like a logger framework in between that could garble the output? Java should be unable to produce that result unless for some reason you have messed up it's "file.separator" system properties. `\\`` being an escape character in many systems could cause trouble if there is something in between println and you. Does `System.out.println(store)` have the same problem?

Comment: What I try to is modifying a configuration file and put within it this path.
I used .replaceAll() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem:

I used  I used replaceAll() method to modify a configuration file, and in the second parameter I put my path (which is C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Test in windows). It is mentionned in the [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string.

So to resolve this problem I did:

```
...
content.replaceAll("root/ca", store.getParent().replaceAll("\\\\", "/") );
```

It works directly on linux because in linux the default file separator is "/".

Answer (score 3):

> What I try to is modifying a configuration file and put within it this path. I used .replaceAll() method.

That's your problem!

Any backslash characters in the 2nd argument of [`String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) are treated as escape characters.  Read the javadocs for details.

In your case, the file separator backspaces are unknown escapes, and `replaceAll` is quietly "eating" them.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the `abstract pathname` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent()

So change your code to `store.getParentFile.getPath()`

Comment: I tried store.getParentFile.getPath() before. it gives the same result. I even tried Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile() ...

Comment: @HakimBenyoucef what about `getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: The same thing.
As I said to @dst, I used .replaceAll() method to modify a configuration file, and in the second parameter I put my path.
Do you think that the problem is there ?

Comment: @HakimBenyoucef easy to test of course! start there